# How to export Jira issues to a csv file programmatically?

Tags: csv, jira

I need to get "in progress" issues from Jira and export them to a CSV file.

How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

[this answer](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/17905613/how-to-export-issues-to-csv-file-programmatically) says that you can use  [getIssueList](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/Reference#Reference-getIssueList) from [JIRA Command Line Interface](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/JIRA+Command+Line+Interface) (CLI) to generate a CSV file from a JQL query.